# Catch Exception when calling python from C#

Tags: c#, python

Thanks to this [post](http://How%20do%20I%20run%20a%20Python%20script%20from%20C#?), I managed to call python script from C#, however, I am not able to detect if the python code threw an exception. For example given a python script

```
def test():
    raise Exception
```

my C# code

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, args)
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
p.Start();

using (StreamReader reader = p.StandardOutput)
{
    string stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

can not read the error message by `string stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` In fact itself threw an exception `"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll"`

How can I solve this?

Comment: What details are contained in `InvalidOperationException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `string stderr = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` you have to redirect the error output 
add `RedirectStandardError = true` 
to your process initialization like so:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, args)
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
p.Start();
```